# Int array to C++ container

Tags: c++, c++98

I've got some data coming from a source in a `int` array. Essentially..

```
// C interface
typedef struct {
    int payload[1024];
    int id;
} tData;

// C++ interface
void MyModule::HandleData(tData *data){
   this->DoUsefulThingsWithData(data->payload);
}
```

This is from a C file written in a functional style. I now want to take this data and use it in my C++ module. Do I pack it all into a vector, or should I just continue to use the data as is? If I use a vector, I don't have to pass a size to `DoUsefulThingsWithData`, but is it worth the overhead? Also I don't exactly know when that data will become irrelevant (scope or freed) so I should copy it into something before continuing to use. What's the best container for this with the lowest overhead on performance (copy) and size? Note: I am in c++ 98

Comment: Mixing `C++` and `C` is quite easy. You do not have to define any special data structures you can use those form `C` in `C++` code. Depending on context it would be more handy to wrap `C` API with `C++` equivalents.

Comment: `payload` has fixed size currently. `void MyModule::DoUsefulThingsWithData(/*const*/ int (&payload)[1024])` would be type safe.

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov - not even close.    `std::vector` is a template and, even correcting for that, does not provide a constructor which will work the way you suggest.    One way might be `std::vector<int> data(payload, payload + sizeof(payload)/sizeof(*payload));`.   C++11 and later (not C++98. which the OP seeks) a clearer alternative is `std::vector<int> data(std::begin(payload), std::end(payload));`

Answer (score 1):

> Do I pack it all into a vector?

Yes:

```
std::vector payload(tData.payload, tData.payload + sizeof(tData.playload));
```

> If I use a vector, I don't have to pass a size to DoUsefulThingsWithData.

Just use `vector`'s [`data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) member function:

```
this->DoUsefulThingsWithData(payload.data());
```

Answer (score 1):

> ... so I should copy it into something before continuing to use.
>
> If I use a vector ... but is it worth the overhead?

Overhead compared to what? `std::vector` is the ideal standard container for this use case.

That said, it's probably best to let `DoUsefulThingsWithData` implementation choose how to store the data if that is what the function does.

> If I use a vector, I don't have to pass a size to `DoUsefulThingsWithData`

You also don't need to pass the size if you use reference to array as the argument type. I recommend this.